# Secure and clean code in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

In fact i have a question about the clean of code
i try to get some value in **blade file** , I Am confused between two approaches
i think both are right but i need to know who's **clean and secure more with the reason**

First approach in my blade directly using Eloquent

```
@foreach
    (Auth::user()->company->country->cities as $city) {{$city->name}}
@endforeach
```

Second approach using Injecting Services by create this method in my model and use it in my blade using laravel 5.1 Injecting Services

```
public function getCity()
{
    foreach(Auth::user()->company->country->cities as $city) {
        return $city->name ;
      // OR 
        return $city ;  
          //  i think this is one of benefits to use this approach   
          //  because in my view i can  use getCity()->id or getCity()->name
    }
}
```

Thanks For Your Time .

Comment: paste your code so we could help you further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to get your data from the model is in the controller, and then pass the data to the view:

This is a key-point of any **MVC** architecture that brings **separation of concerns**: your controller's purpose is to get the data from the model and to pass it to the views. The purpose of the view is to get the data from the controller and to present it. So, the only thing a view needs is a variable passed from the controller

This way the app logic is kept in the controller and it will be easy for you to mantain your application. So:

In your controller:

```php
public function index()
{
    //get data from model
    $cities = Auth::user()->company->country->cities; 

    //pass the data to the view 
    return View::make('your_view', ['cities' => $cities] );
}
```

Then, in your view:

```php
@foreach ($cities as $city)
     {{$city->name}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 4):

Your second approach wouldn't work, because the function will finish while returning the name of the first city (or the first city itself). To make it work you could rewrite it, so that it returns all cities and loop through them in blade.

So if you use that function your code might look like:

```
@foreach($serviceName->getCities() as $city)
    {{ $city->name }}
@endforeach
```

which is a nice thing, because the view doesn't have to care about where the cities will come from. If you use such a service on different views, it will be much easier to update.

Regarding security: There is no difference between those two approaches. As long as you print your output using the '{{ }}' operator. It'll prevent possible [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) attacks.

Answer (score 2):

I think The best way that achieves **MVC** Design pattern whatever your code

```
 public function getCities()
 {
//in your model model
   return $cities = Auth::user()->company->country->cities; 
 }

 public function index()
{
     //call return getCities(); 
}

 //finally in your view loop over $cities 
  @foreach ($cities as $city)
    {{$city->name}}
  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup eloquent relationship correctly then you should get the cities by using the following code

```
foreach(Auth::user()->cities as $city)
{
   {!! $city->whatever !!}
}
```